# how to create a custom JsonDeserializer in Java?

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I have a `Map<A,B> fieldOfC` as a field of a class C. When I try to deserialize C with Jackson, an Exception is thrown because it can't find a Deserializer for Map's key A. So, I guess the solution is to extend StdJsonDeserializer and do it manually.
My problem is that I can't find an example on how to use the parser and the context of the method "deserialize" that I have to implement.

Can anyone write the code for this simple example so I can use it as a start to build my real deserializer?

```
public class A{
  private String a1;
  private Integer a2;
}

public class B{
  private String b1;
}

public class C{
  @JsonDeserialize(keyUsing=ADeserializer.class)
  //also tried this: @JsonDeserialize(keyAs=A.class) without success
  private Map<A,B> fieldOfC;
  private String c1;
}

public class ADeserializer extends StdKeyDeserializer {

  protected ADeserializer(Class<A> cls) {
    super(cls);
  }

  protected Object _parse(String key, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper.readValue(key, A.class);
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**: googling, I found a [test](http://archive.codehaus.org/lists/org.codehaus.jackson.user/msg/ceb609d80910021829r61997ec0q5fc64e926779f4c0@mail.gmail.com) of the same problem I have. This is exactly my problem

**EDIT**: changed extended class from StdDeserializer to StdKeyDeserializer as I read [here](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.7.0/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/DeserializerProvider.html) in method `findKeyDeserializer(org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig, org.codehaus.jackson.type.JavaType, org.codehaus.jackson.map.BeanProperty)`

**EDIT**: After solving this issue I got [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5614654/288247) that is related.

Comment: I know this is not a solution quite yet, but Jackson 1.8 has full support for custom key serializers and deserializers, both via annotations and through Module API. So it should help a lot: this has been painful to do properly with earlier versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am a complete newbie with Jackson, but the following works for me.

First I add a JsonCreator method to A:

```
public class A {
    private String a1;
    private Integer a2;
    public String getA1() { return a1; }
    public Integer getA2() { return a2; }
    public void setA1(String a1) { this.a1 = a1; }
    public void setA2(Integer a2) { this.a2 = a2; }
    
    @JsonCreator
    public static A fromJSON(String val) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        A a = mapper.readValue(val,A.class);
        return a;
    }
}
```

That alone solves the deserialization problem. The harder part for me was the correct serialization of the keys. What I did there was to define a key serializer that serializes named classes as there JSON serialization, like this:

```
public class KeySerializer extends SerializerBase<Object> {
    private static final SerializerBase<Object> DEFAULT = new StdKeySerializer();

    private Set<Class<?>> objectKeys_ = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Class<?>>());

    protected KeySerializer(Class<?>... objectKeys) {
        super(Object.class);
        for(Class<?> cl:objectKeys) {
            objectKeys_.add(cl);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public JsonNode getSchema(SerializerProvider provider, Type typeHint) throws JsonMappingException {
        return DEFAULT.getSchema(provider, typeHint);
    }


    @Override
    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator jgen,
            SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
            JsonGenerationException {
        if (objectKeys_.contains(value.getClass())) {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            mapper.writeValue(writer, value);
            jgen.writeFieldName(writer.toString());
        } else {
            DEFAULT.serialize(value, jgen, provider);
        }
    }
}
```

Then to prove it works, serializing and deserializing an instance of class C:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    StdSerializerProvider provider = new StdSerializerProvider();
    provider.setKeySerializer(new KeySerializer(A.class));
    mapper.setSerializerProvider(provider);
    
    StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
    mapper.writeValue(out, c);
    String json = out.toString();
    System.out.println("JSON= "+json);
    
    C c2 = mapper.readValue(json, C.class);
    System.out.print("C2= ");
    StringWriter outC2 = new StringWriter();
    mapper.writeValue(outC2, c2);
    System.out.println(outC2.toString());
```

For me this produced the output:

```
JSON = {"c1":"goo","map":{"{\"a1\":\"1ccf\",\"a2\":7376}":{"b1":"5ox"},"{\"a1\":\"1cd2\",\"a2\":7379}":{"b1":"5p0"},"{\"a1\":\"1cd5\",\"a2\":7382}":{"b1":"5p3"},"{\"a1\":\"1cd8\",\"a2\":7385}":{"b1":"5p6"}}}
C2 =   {"c1":"goo","map":{"{\"a1\":\"1ccf\",\"a2\":7376}":{"b1":"5ox"},"{\"a1\":\"1cd2\",\"a2\":7379}":{"b1":"5p0"},"{\"a1\":\"1cd5\",\"a2\":7382}":{"b1":"5p3"},"{\"a1\":\"1cd8\",\"a2\":7385}":{"b1":"5p6"}}}
```

I feel there ought to have been a better way of doing saying how to serialize the key by using annotations, but I could not work it out.

Comment: I will try to merge this solution with what I'm trying to do with StdKeyDeserializer and see if I find a better way.

Comment: I used your solution, the only different thing is that I implemented the serialize method without using the objectKeys attribute. My implementation is exactly the four lines that you have inside if block. Now I'm having problems with Period joda-time's class, but I will make a new post with that one. Thanks, Simon.