# Deserialise Json to class with Generic fields

Tags: java, json, jackson

I currently have the following class

```
public class Setting<T> {
    private T value;
    private T defaultValue;

    /* getters and setters */
}
```

The trouble I'm having is deserializing from the Json, for example, having a Setting will work fine if the Json is

```
{ \"value\": true, \"defaultValue\": false }
```

.. but, it will also accept

```
{ \"value\": \"true\", \"defaultValue\": \"false\" }
```

Even tho the field is of Setting. From what I understand, Java strips away all the generic info, so jackson cannot look it up at runtime. I have tried the following

```
Field currentSettingField = currentSettingsObject.getClass().getDeclaredField("mySetting");
if (currentSettingField != null) {
    JavaType settingType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructType(settingField.getGenericType(), Setting.class);
    Setting setting = objectMapper.readValue(currentSettingNode.toString(), settingType);
}
```

Which has been somewhat successful, however I can still do things like converting a String or Integer value from Json to a type of Setting. Am I doing something wrong here, or would I be better just have a simple marker interface, then derive each type of setting I want from it?

Comment: Maybe to explain it a bit better - I want deserialization to fail if the types aren't as expected - so even though, say, a String of "true" could be deserialized to Boolean true, I would want that to fail

Answer (score 0):

From what I see from Jackson's code, it tries it's best to guess the value for the `boolean` and matches strings:

```
// And finally, let's allow Strings to be converted too
if (t == JsonToken.VALUE_STRING) {
    String text = jp.getText().trim();
    if ("true".equals(text)) {
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }
    if ("false".equals(text)) {
        return Boolean.FALSE;
    }
    if (text.length() == 0) {
        return (Boolean) getEmptyValue();
    }
    throw ctxt.weirdStringException(text, _valueClass, "only \"true\" or \"false\" recognized");
}
```

So if you change you generic type to Integer or provide an incorrect input i.e. `'tru'`, it won't able to match it.

> "Java strips away all the generic info"

AFAIK, Java can do this, but it doesn't remove type attributes information from classes. It doesn't use them however during runtime. This make possible for libraries like Jackson are able to use it.

Comment: Yeah, even an Integer value will try to be parsed to the Boolean (0 is true, anything else to False)... only trouble is, what I want is for it to fail unless it is a Boolean value going to a Setting<Boolean>, even if it is a valid boolean value wrapped in a String, very frustrating cause it sounds so simple!

Comment: Writing a custom serializer for a Boolean field or for a complete class may sound ridiculous, but can be helpful, I can't say for sure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609321/how-to-create-a-custom-jsondeserializer-in-java

Comment: Yeah, I've been trying to to avoid that as it seems a bit overkill for the problem I have, althought as a last resort I may have to, just to perform the validation I need to